# How can I prevent text from going out of the grid (make in centered)?

Tags: html, css

I am designing this website for my introductory course. They require flex/grid layouts (although we didn't cover this in class). I decided to follow a youtube tutorial that was making a grid with 3 columns (1fr each). It then added a background to every "cell". In every "cell" I have a title and a description. I want to style the title and description in each "cell" to always be in the center, no matter the sizing of the page. I have managed to make the text adjust its size to the dimension of the page, but the title still overflows to the right when I minimize the window's width.
This is what I mean by overflow: [image]

As you might guess, when the width is too large, the title tends to go to the right. This is the code (I no longer have images as background but you get the idea):

```js
const portfolioItems = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio-item-wrapper');
    portfolioItems.forEach(portfolioItem => { //pentru fiecare item din portofolioItem vad cand am mouse pe el
        portfolioItem.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            portfolioItem.childNodes[1].classList.add('img-darken');//si cand am mouse-ul pe el iau primul copil
            //care este portofolio-img-background
        })
        portfolioItem.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            portfolioItem.childNodes[1].classList.remove('img-darken');
        })
    })
```

```css
.portfolio-items-wrapper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.portfolio-item-wrapper{
    position:relative;
}

.portfolio-img-background{
    height:350px;
    width: auto;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.portfolio-img-background:nth-of-type(odd)
{
    background-color: maroon;
}

.portfolio-img-background:nth-of-type(even)
{
    background-color: rgb(101, 172, 122);
}


.title-text-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

#italian{
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

#american{
    font-family: 'Mitr';
}

.title-wrapper div{
    justify-content: center;
    font-size:5vw;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
}

/* Needs to be more specific with selector*/

.title-text-wrapper .subtitle{
    transition: 1s;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: transparent; 
    align-self: center;;
}

.title-text-wrapper:hover .subtitle{
    font-weight: 600;
    color: lightseagreen;
}

.img-darken{
    transition: 1s;
    filter: brightness(10%);
}
.logo-wrapper{
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="portfolio-items-wrapper">

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                        <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio1.jpg);"></div>
                        <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                            <div class="title-wrapper">
                                <div id="american">American</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="subtitle">
                                    This is a description of american food.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio2.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="italian">Italian</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio3.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="chinese">Asian</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio4.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="mexican">Mexican</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio5.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="romanian">Romanian</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio8.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="barbeque">Barbeque</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">
                                Item
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio9.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="indian">Indian</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">
                                Item
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio10.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="chinese">Chinese</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">
                                Item
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio11.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="mediteranean">Mediteranean</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio12.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="desserts">Desserts</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio6.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="smoothies">Smoothies</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio7.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="coffee">Coffee</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm a beginner at this, so I would appreciate your advice on anything that's wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is you are using `padding` left right to make item in `center`, I removed that and make its `width:100%` as you are using `flex` so its `align center` already

```js
const portfolioItems = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio-item-wrapper');
    portfolioItems.forEach(portfolioItem => { //pentru fiecare item din portofolioItem vad cand am mouse pe el
        portfolioItem.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            portfolioItem.childNodes[1].classList.add('img-darken');//si cand am mouse-ul pe el iau primul copil
            //care este portofolio-img-background
        })
        portfolioItem.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            portfolioItem.childNodes[1].classList.remove('img-darken');
        })
    })
```

```css
.portfolio-items-wrapper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.portfolio-item-wrapper{
    position:relative;
}

.portfolio-img-background{
    height:350px;
    width: auto;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.portfolio-img-background:nth-of-type(odd)
{
    background-color: maroon;
}

.portfolio-img-background:nth-of-type(even)
{
    background-color: rgb(101, 172, 122);
}


.title-text-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#italian{
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

#american{
    font-family: 'Mitr';
}

.title-wrapper div{
    justify-content: center;
    font-size:5vw;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
}

/* Needs to be more specific with selector*/

.title-text-wrapper .subtitle{
    transition: 1s;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: transparent; 
    align-self: center;
}

.title-text-wrapper:hover .subtitle{
    font-weight: 600;
    color: lightseagreen;
}

.img-darken{
    transition: 1s;
    filter: brightness(10%);
}
.logo-wrapper{
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="portfolio-items-wrapper">

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                        <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio1.jpg);"></div>
                        <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                            <div class="title-wrapper">
                                <div id="american">American</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="subtitle">
                                    This is a description of american food.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio2.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="italian">Italian</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio3.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="chinese">Asian</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio4.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="mexican">Mexican</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio5.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="romanian">Romanian</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio8.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="barbeque">Barbeque</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">
                                Item
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio9.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="indian">Indian</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">
                                Item
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio10.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="chinese">Chinese</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">
                                Item
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio11.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="mediteranean">Mediteranean</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio12.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="desserts">Desserts</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio6.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="smoothies">Smoothies</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                    <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/Portfolio7.jpg);"></div>
                    <div class="title-text-wrapper">
                        <div class="title-wrapper">
                            <div id="coffee">Coffee</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="subtitle">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```